# What is the difference between a BitLocker startup and recovery key?

Tags: bitlocker, disk-encryption

I would like to encrypt a system partition using BitLocker using a password (`manage-bde -protectors -add c: -pw`), but (safely) store a key elsewhere if I ever forget the password.

Should I add a recovery key (`-rk`) or a startup key (`-sk`)?

It seems that I would be able to use both for accessing data in case of emergency.

Is there anything that I could do with a recovery key that I could not do with a startup key and vice versa?

Answer (score 4):

### 2016-05:

I also wondered this and experimented; this is what I know so far:

- Both commands create an external *.BEK keyfile.
- After you have created a `-StartupKey` and `-RecoveryKey` they become inseparable in the protector-overview. (`manage-bde C: -protectors -get`) This lists all keys and labels the keys in question **'External key'**. Only if you remember the {id}, you can tell the difference.

*I cannot find any sources that can validate claims/explanations about this topic, however, part of an answer might help/trigger one:*

I suspect it is a legacy issue. A command was introduced into an earlier version of Bitlocker and later one it was expanded. Nowadays it might make more sense to call it `(-)ExternalKey` which by the way, you can actually use to define a `-type` if you use the `-delete` command to revoke all Externalkeyfile-access from a drive.

In contrast, if we move a fixed(*) drive to another system (or Bitlocker detects system-compromising-integrity changes), it can apparently **demand** for a **recovery password**. If we expand the language, a recovery key also is able to unlock the drive:

- I can confirm that [Load key from USB-station]-button works with both key-type. (Multiboot, unlocked system drive of other OS.) However, Bitlocker was not in 'Recovery mode' that might be triggered by certain changes.
- I can confirm that you can boot a system from a -RecoveryKey. (Might be obvious, but just to be complete.)

So the remaining question: if the Bitlocker protection mechanism is triggered, will the Startupkey still be able to unlock a drive?

At this point I think it would be bad design if you could not, as you cannot differentiate between the key-id's nor the *.bek files. (*.sbek, *.rbek do not exist.) However, I have not been able to validate my assumptions. Nonetheless, I think the dots provide insight.

### Update 2022-05:

This answer (originally) from 2016 applies to a computer *without* TPM.

To extend on the [answer from 2018](https://superuser.com/questions/1075220/what-is-the-difference-between-a-bitlocker-startup-and-recovery-key/#1303188) below/above mentioned:

If you configure BitLocker on a computer **with a TPM**, with a protecter `-TPMAndStartupKey` or `-TPMAndPINAndStartupKey` for the system drive, it behaves like a multi-factor. To unlock the sytem drive, you need all of the factors.

Then, the difference between Start-up Key and Recovery-Key is significant. A recovery key will then be able to boot the Windows drive without needing the TPM-hardware or PIN. A Startup key will only contain half of the secret to unlock the Windows partition, the orther half will be inside the TPM.

So if you move the drive to other hardware and you want to boot from it, the new TPM will not have the required secret and you would require the Recovery Key (or Recovery Password) to unlock.

If you want to mount the drive (as data drive) on the same hardware (multi-boot for example), you cannot use the TPM and Startup key to do so. You cannot lock or unlock a data-drive with a TPM+factors directly. (Only by using `-Certificate` protector and configuring a smartcard inside a TPM.) So, if you want to unlock your Windows drive in another Windows, you would require the Recovery Key (or Recovery Password).

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, one difference is that:

- If the PC is configured to normally use a TPM to perform a measured boot, it will do so when the **startup key** is used, but [not when a **recovery key** is used](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/information-protection/bitlocker/bitlocker-frequently-asked-questions#bkmk-usbdrive). So, the **recovery key** should only be used as a last resort.

I will update this answer with additional differences if I discover any.

Comment: Someone seems to have downvoted this answer without explaining why. That is an unhelpful thing to do. If you are considering downvoting this answer, please at least leave a comment with the reason why you think this is appropriate, so that those of us to whom your reason would not otherwise be clear might learn from it. After all, improving people's understanding is the purpose of this site. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, the sk would be kept on removable media and you would need this media present to start your machine each time.

The alternative would be a PIN. If you used a pin, but forgot it, you would be able to access your machine with reference to the related rk, which would be stored safely elsewhere.

A PIN would be more convenient, unless you had trouble remembering it.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on user11574's answer...

[BitLocker key protectors](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/information-protection/bitlocker/prepare-your-organization-for-bitlocker-planning-and-policies#bitlocker-key-protectors)

[image]

Also, if `manage-bde -on` is run with both `-rk` and `-sk` options:

```
manage-bde -on c: -rk "d:\keys" -sk d: -used -em xts_aes128 -rvsc
```

***note:** saving recovery and startup keys to the same drive isn't recommended (see below)*

then they are both added as "external key" protectors:

```
Key Protectors Added:

    Saved to directory d:\keys

    External Key:
      ID: {RK000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
      External Key File Name:
        RK000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000.BEK

    Saved to directory d:

    External Key:
      ID: {SK000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
      External Key File Name:
        SK000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000.BEK

    TPM:
      ID: {TPM00000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
      PCR Validation Profile:
        7, 11
        (Uses Secure Boot for integrity validation)
```

This can also be confirmed with `manage-bde -status`:

```
Size:                 715.00 GB
BitLocker Version:    2.0
Conversion Status:    Fully Decrypted
Percentage Encrypted: 0.0%
Encryption Method:    XTS-AES 128
Protection Status:    Protection Off
Lock Status:          Unlocked
Identification Field: Unknown
Key Protectors:
    External Key
    External Key
    TPM
```

So at this level anyway Bitlocker seems to make no distinction between recovery and startup keys. `manage-bde -on -h` even suggests that they're interchageable:

```
-RecoveryKey or -rk
            Adds an External Key protector for recovery. Optional. Provide
            the absolute directory path where the file containing the
            randomly-generated external key will be saved. Example: "E:"
-StartupKey or -sk
            Adds an External Key protector for startup. Required if the
            computer does not have a supported TPM and one has not already
            been added. To use a startup key, the saved external key file
            must be located on the root directory of a USB flash drive.
            Since both the -RecoveryKey and -StartupKey parameters produce
            External Key protectors, the saved files can be used
            interchangeably.
```

`manage-bde -protectors -get -h` seconds this notion:

```
-SaveExternalKey or -sek
            Provide the absolute directory path to save file(s) containing
            displayed external key(s). These external key files may be
            used as startup or recovery keys.
```

---

[Can the USB flash drive that is used as the startup key also be used to store the recovery key?](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/hh831507(v=ws.11)#can-the-usb-flash-drive-that-is-used-as-the-startup-key-also-be-used-to-store-the-recovery-key)

> While this is technically possible, it is not a best practice to use one USB flash drive to store both keys. If the USB flash drive that contains your startup key is lost or stolen, you also lose access to your recovery key. In addition, inserting this key would cause your computer to automatically boot from the recovery key even if TPM-measured files have changed, which circumvents the TPM's system integrity check.

I believe however that in this particular case what is being referred to as a "recovery key" is actually a "numerical password", of which can be exported from either Control Panel (as a *.txt* file) or `manage-bde`:

[image]

```
manage-bde -protectors -get c:

    Numerical Password:
      ID: {NP000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
      Password:
        000000-000000-000000-000000-000000-000000-000000-000000
```

ref: [bitlocker - how to create recovery key?](https://superuser.com/a/1438727/235989)