# BitLocker: specify startup key? (Enable same startup key to be used with multiple PCs.)

Tags: windows-10, bitlocker, disk-encryption

#### Background

By default, Microsoft [BitLocker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitLocker) does not allow the user to enable full disk encryption (FDE) of the system disk, unless the PC has a compatible [TPM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Platform_Module).

However, if the "Allow BitLocker without a compatible TPM" option is turned on (under *Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> BitLocker Drive Encryption -> Operating System Drives -> Require additional authentication at startup*), then the BitLocker [wizard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wizard_(software)) will permit FDE of the system disk. If this is done, then one of the wizard's dialogue boxes, headed "Choose how to unlock your drive at startup", will require the user to choose between two alternative authentication mechanisms:

- Insert a USB flash drive;
- Enter a password.

If the user picks "Insert a USB flash drive", then typically the wizard will generate a "**startup key**" and will ask for a USB flash drive on which to write it.

(The idea is that when wanting to boot the PC in the future, the user will *first* insert that USB flash drive into the PC and *then* switch on the PC. The Windows bootloader will then read the **startup key** from the flash drive in order to decrypt the system disk before booting Windows. I know people who do this in practice, and it works well. For more background, see e.g. [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mvpawardprogram/2016/01/12/securing-windows-10-with-bitlocker-drive-encryption/) and [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1075220/what-is-the-difference-between-a-bitlocker-startup-and-recovery-key).)

#### My question

When encrypting a drive with BitLocker, so as to require a **startup key**, can the user specify *her own custom* **startup key** (e.g. if she has previously generated one with the wizard and wants to use it on additional PCs), or must she accept the key generated by the BitLocker wizard?

Alternatively, if she must accept the key created by the BitLocker wizard (at least while the wizard is running) then as a workaround, can she *later* replace this with her preferred **startup key**? Via the BitLocker Manage Keys interface, perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot make your own startup key or import startup keys, BUT:

> When encrypting a drive with BitLocker, so as to require a startup
>   key, can the user specify her own custom startup key (e.g. if she has
>   previously generated one with the wizard and wants to use it on
>   additional PCs), or must she accept the key generated by the BitLocker
>   wizard?

In this example, if she is wishing to use the *same* startup key on multiple computers, it cannot be done.  But, she CAN have the startup keys from different computers on the same USB.
I do want to add that you may think that manage-bde -add could be used to "add" your own startup key as a protector, but it just creates a new startup key and adds it as a protector.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question:

> When encrypting a drive with BitLocker, so as to require a startup key, can the user specify her own custom startup key (e.g. if she has previously generated one with the wizard and wants to use it on additional PCs), or must she accept the key generated by the BitLocker wizard?

**The answer** is that we have to accepted the key generated by Bitlocer.

> Alternatively, if she must accept the key created by the BitLocker wizard (at least while the wizard is running) then as a workaround, can she later replace this with her preferred startup key? Via the BitLocker Manage Keys interface, perhaps?

**The answer** is that we cannot do this.

Comment: Thanks. I fear you may be correct. At least, I haven't found any *documented* way to achieve either the desired outcome or the workaround. But nor have I yet found any documentation that confirms your answer. If you know of any, please can you link to it from your answer? Thanks :)