# bitlocker - how to create recovery key?

Tags: windows-server-2012, bitlocker

I have a w2k12 system on which I enabled bitlocker on my D: drive. I cannot use TPM, because there is no w2k12 driver for that module which fits my motherboard, so I used USB flash to store the key. Weirdly the wizard did not offer me to use USB flash to store the key when enabling bitlocker on D drive (6TB), but it DID show this option for drive C. Why? Anyway I made it using these commands instead:

```
manage-bde -protectors -add d: -startupkey e: (e: being the flash drive)
manage-bde -on d:
```

Then I waited several days and now it says

```
PS C:\> manage-bde -status d:
BitLocker Drive Encryption: Configuration Tool version 6.3.9600
Copyright (C) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Volume D: [WD6TB]
[Data Volume]

    Size:                 5588.90 GB
    BitLocker Version:    2.0
    Conversion Status:    Fully Encrypted
    Percentage Encrypted: 100.0%
    Encryption Method:    AES 128
    Protection Status:    Protection On
    Lock Status:          Unlocked
    Identification Field: Unknown
    Automatic Unlock:     Disabled
    Key Protectors:
        External Key
```

If I look into manage bitlocker control panel I don't see "backup your recovery key"
[image]

How do I get the recovery key? This is a server OS, so I did this all while logged on as administrator. I don't have a microsoft account tied to it.

Answer (score 3):

I think that
the problem may be that the BitLocker drive just does not have a Recovery Key
as one of its BitLocker *Protectors*.

Bitlocker can unlock your drive with various types of *Protectors* such as
TPM, Password, and Recovery Key.

To see the available types, run:

```
manage-bde -protectors d: -get
```

You’ll see the 48-digit password that is the BitLocker recovery key under "Numerical Password":

[image]

A "Recovery Key" or "Startup Key" has a corresponding "External Key",
which is saved in a `.BEK` file.
These two *Protectors* are not mandatory, so your drive may not have one assigned.

To save the `.BEK` key file you need an "External Key" protector
listed when you run the above command.

If missing, you can add a Recovery Key to the drive with the command below,
which will also back it up to a `.BEK` file in, for example `f:\folder`:

```
manage-bde -protectors -add d: -RecoveryKey f:\folder
```

Then, when you run the command below it will save a `.BEK` file to the directory
`f:\folder`:

```
manage-bde -protectors -get d: -sek f:\folder
```

---

Finally the problem was that the Numerical Password protector,
also known as `RecoveryPassword` was missing, as it was probably not
specified when the volume was locked.

An example of a command to enable BitLocker on the C drive,
store the recovery key on the Y drive, and generate a random recovery password,
is:

```
manage-bde -on C: -RecoveryKey Y: -RecoveryPassword
```

If the paramater `RecoveryPassword` was not specified when enabling BitLocker,
this protector can later be added by using the command:

```
 manage-bde –protectors –add C: -RecoveryPassword
```

Comment: C:\> manage-bde -protectors d: -get
Volume D: [WD6TB]
All Key Protectors

   External Key:
     ID: {A1625DE1-0B36-44E2-A039-38B5F4D34753}
     External Key File Name:
       A1625DE1-0B36-44E2-A039-38B5F4D34753.BEK

so I see there is only External key. Thinking that manage-bde -protectors -add d: -RecoveryKey f:\folder will add the numerical password from your screenshot I did it but now I just have two binary .BEK files on my flash drive, but not this numerical password. Maybe I don't understand it, but I want two ways to unlock - USBflash and that recovery key in case of problem.

Comment: You seem to be missing the Numerical Password protector, also known as `RecoveryPassword`. Try adding it using  `manage-bde –protectors –add d: -RecoveryPassword`. More info [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/information-protection/bitlocker/bitlocker-recovery-guide-plan).

Comment: yes that worked!
PS C:\>  manage-bde -protectors -add d: -RecoveryPassword
BitLocker Drive Encryption: Configuration Tool version 6.3.9600
Copyright (C) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Key Protectors Added:

    Numerical Password:
      ID: 
      Password:
password

Comment: If my answer has helped with the problem, please accept it.

Comment: it was not your answer but the comment. Anyway seems like I was wrong, or something's wrong, because upon reboot the drive is NOT automatically unlocked via key on USB drive. When I double click on it in explorer it asks me for this 48digit recovery key! Or I can click "use key on USB drive". THat is not what I wanted. I suppose recovery key is intended to use in case I lose/damage my flash drive and don't have backup for example and in such case I use recovery key to recover it. Why does it ask for it primarily?

Comment: PS C:\> manage-bde -autounlock d: -enable
BitLocker Drive Encryption: Configuration Tool version 6.3.9600
Copyright (C) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

ERROR: An error occurred (code 0x80310020):
The operating system drive is not protected by BitLocker Drive Encryption.

Do I need bitlocker on C: as well to be able to have D: autounlocked upon reboot?